# Drop down menu opens all sub menus

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have created a sidebar menu with MDL, and currently I am trying to solve dropdown menu issue. After clicking on menu item, it should open sub menus just for a single menu item, but it opens them all - every single menu item that has sub menus.

HTML

```
<li>
     <a class="mdl-navigation__link havesub_nav" href="javascript:void(0);">
                    <i  class="material-icons" role="presentation">create</i>
                                <?php echo $text_accounting; ?>
                                <i class="material-icons arrow_invert" role="presentation">chevron_right</i>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <ul class="sub_nav">
                            <li>
                                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<?php echo $account; ?>">
                                    <i class="material-icons" role="presentation" style="font-size: 16px; margin-left: 30px; width: 0px;">chevron_right</i>
                                    <?php echo $text_account; ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li >
                                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<?php echo $currency; ?>">
                                    <i class="material-icons" role="presentation" style="font-size: 16px; margin-left: 30px; width: 0px;">chevron_right</i>
                                    <?php echo $text_currency; ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li >
                                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<?php echo $inventory; ?>">
                                    <i class="material-icons" role="presentation" style="font-size: 16px; margin-left: 30px; width: 0px;">chevron_right</i>
                                    <?php echo $text_inventory; ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li >
                                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<?php echo $journal; ?>">
                                    <i class="material-icons" role="presentation" style="font-size: 16px; margin-left: 30px; width: 0px;">chevron_right</i>
                                    <?php echo $text_journal; ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.havesub_nav').click(function(){
        $('.arrow_invert').toggleClass("transform_arrow");
        $('.sub_nav').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you refer to all elements, like in:

```
$('.arrow_invert').toggleClass("transform_arrow");
```

Change such lines with a local search:

```
$(this).find('.arrow_invert').toggleClass("transform_arrow");
```

An example:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.havesub_nav').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.arrow_invert').toggleClass("transform_arrow");
    $(this).next('.sub_nav').slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link havesub_nav" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <i  class="material-icons" role="presentation">create</i>
        <?php echo $text_accounting; ?>
        <i class="material-icons arrow_invert" role="presentation">chevron_right</i>
    </a>
    </strong>
    <ul class="sub_nav">
        <li>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<?php echo $account; ?>">
                <i class="material-icons" role="presentation" style="font-size: 16px; margin-left: 30px; width: 0px;">chevron_right</i>
                <?php echo $text_account; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<?php echo $currency; ?>">
                <i class="material-icons" role="presentation" style="font-size: 16px; margin-left: 30px; width: 0px;">chevron_right</i>
                <?php echo $text_currency; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<?php echo $inventory; ?>">
                <i class="material-icons" role="presentation" style="font-size: 16px; margin-left: 30px; width: 0px;">chevron_right</i>
                <?php echo $text_inventory; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<?php echo $journal; ?>">
                <i class="material-icons" role="presentation" style="font-size: 16px; margin-left: 30px; width: 0px;">chevron_right</i>
                <?php echo $text_journal; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link havesub_nav" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <i  class="material-icons" role="presentation">create</i>
        <?php echo $text_accounting; ?>
        <i class="material-icons arrow_invert" role="presentation">chevron_right</i>
    </a>
    </strong>
    <ul class="sub_nav">
        <li>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<?php echo $account; ?>">
                <i class="material-icons" role="presentation" style="font-size: 16px; margin-left: 30px; width: 0px;">chevron_right</i>
                <?php echo $text_account; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<?php echo $currency; ?>">
                <i class="material-icons" role="presentation" style="font-size: 16px; margin-left: 30px; width: 0px;">chevron_right</i>
                <?php echo $text_currency; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<?php echo $inventory; ?>">
                <i class="material-icons" role="presentation" style="font-size: 16px; margin-left: 30px; width: 0px;">chevron_right</i>
                <?php echo $text_inventory; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<?php echo $journal; ?>">
                <i class="material-icons" role="presentation" style="font-size: 16px; margin-left: 30px; width: 0px;">chevron_right</i>
                <?php echo $text_journal; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a quick look, can you try the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.havesub_nav').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.arrow_invert').toggleClass("transform_arrow");
        $(this).next('.sub_nav').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```